# Is there a Javascript equivalent to pytest's parameterized fixtures?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, pytest

In pytest you can set up fixtures that can have multiple different values. These are called "parameterized fixtures". A test that uses these fixtures will be run with all possible combinations of values from those fixtures.

**Example**

```
# Fixture `a` can have the values `1` and `2`
@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2])
def a(request):
    yield request.param

# Fixture `b` can have the values `3` and `4`
@pytest.fixture(params=[3, 4])
def b(request):
    yield request.param

# The test `test_sum` uses the fixtures `a` and `b`
def test_sum(a, b):
    assert sum([a, b]) == a + b
```

Here, the function `test_sum` will be run four times in total. Each run will use different arguments: `a=1, b=3`, `a=1, b=4`, `a=2, b=3`, and `a=2, b=4` respectively.

**Question**

Is there an equivalent to parametrized fixtures in any Javascript testing library? (We currently use mocha, so that would be the most interesting to us)

Comment: I'm looking for the same stuff.  Surprisely, pytest's fixture alike feature  has been [requested for years](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1437).  However,  
   these JS testing frontiers never really understand how elegant the tests can be when with builtin fixture.

Answer (score 4):

Jest now incorporated the utility into its codebase :) It's under [`it.each`/`test.each`](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout). For older versions of jest, you can use one of the libraries mentioned below.

### Old answer:

Recently, I discovered there is a utility for Jest called [jest-each](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-each) or with less nice syntax [jest-in-case](https://github.com/atlassian/jest-in-case) which is quite a good alternative to `pytest.mark.parametrized`.

### Old old original answer below:

Unfortunately no. Mocha does not support it even today from what I found on the internet. There is also [rejected proposal(s)](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1454) for such syntax, but currently, the only solution is something that they call [dynamically generating tests](https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests) and the syntax looks like in the code below (taken from the doc). Also, you can read more about [sad state of JS vs. Python testing](http://honzajavorek.cz/blog/testing-in-javascript-and-in-python).

```js
describe('Possible user names behaves correctly ', () => {
  const TEST_CASES = [
    {args: ['rj'], expected: false},
    {args: ['rj12345'], expected: false},
    {args: ['rj123'], expected: true},
  ]

  TEST_CASES.forEach((testCase) => {
    it(`check user name ${JSON.stringify(testCase.args)}`, () => {
      const result = checkUserName.apply(this, testCase.args)

      expect(testCase.expected).toEqual(result)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered the need for parameterized tests for both python and js, I think the one that is both easy to use and readable is the `.each` syntax included in Jest (sorry, haven't found options for Mocha!).

A good example can be found here: https://dev.to/flyingdot/data-driven-unit-tests-with-jest-26bh

Answer (score 0):

[Playwright Test](https://playwright.dev) testing framework borrows this concept from PyTest; see https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures for details.